# Odd Effect of pandas.to_csv()

Tags: python-2.7, csv, pandas, export-to-csv

I have created a fairly large dataframe, and when I write it into a csv file using

```
dataframe.to_csv('test.csv',sep=',')
```

And I scroll down to around line 75, the data starts to look really weird, clearing up again at row 81.

For instance, if I go into a specific cell, it shows random data that shouldn't be there, but when I load up the csv file into a dataframe again:

```
df = read_table('test.csv',sep=',')
```

and I look for that cell:

```
df['line_item_id''][75]
```

...it displays it correctly.  Not a huge deal because I can just do everything in Pandas and not worry about the csv portion of it, but I was wondering if anyone else has ever ran into or know something about this.

Comment: well, what does your frame look like, do you have unicode?

Comment: Make an effort to use the word 'random' in its proper place. It isn't random just because you don't understand the process that's generating the unexpected data.